# How to make an array of values that englobes other values?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, web, merge

I'm making a script in javascript and I have to do something that reads an array of numbers and returns a unique array that "englobes" values. The array I have looks like this: [100, 200, 500, 600, 150, 250]

Values are paired in two. So it's like A: 100-200, B: 500-600, C:150-250.

In an image it would look something like this. (Please excuse this mediocre drawing I made on MS Paint)

[image: http://i.imgur.com/z5ZNgs9.png]

So basically, what I want is the pink line. The resulting array would be [100, 250, 500, 600]

I hope this is clear enough.

Comment: Please post the code that you attempted.

Comment: I would but I don't have anything that makes much sense so far, sorry!

Comment: What you are tried?? Post some code..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very common problem.

```
var array  = [100, 200, 500, 600, 150, 250], temp = [], result = [];

// Group the array in proper ranges
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i += 2) {
    temp.push([array[i], array[i + 1]]);
}
console.log(temp);
# [ [ 100, 200 ], [ 500, 600 ], [ 150, 250 ] ]

// Sort the array based on the first starting number of the range
temp.sort(function(first, second) {
    return first[0] - second[0];
});
console.log(temp);
# [ [ 100, 200 ], [ 150, 250 ], [ 500, 600 ] ]

// Push the First range in the result
result.push(temp[0]);

// See the `explanation` below
for (var i = 1; i < temp.length; i += 1) {
    var top = result[0], cur = temp[i];
    if ((cur[0] < top[0] && cur[1] >= top[0]) || (cur[0] < top[1])) {
        result[0] = [Math.min(cur[0], top[0]), Math.max(cur[1], top[1])];
    } else {
        result.splice(0, 0, cur);
    }
}
console.log(result);
# [ [ 500, 600 ], [ 100, 250 ] ]

// Now, flatten the data and sort.
console.log([].concat.apply([], result).sort());
# [ 100, 250, 500, 600 ]
```

**Explanation**

For every element in the `temp`, check if it is in the range of the first
element of the `result`. Basically we are going to use `result` as a stack.
If the current range overlaps with the top of the `result`, then replace
top of the `result` with the range which encloses both the elements

Comment: I tried you version and put it with the code I have and it works! Thank you so much, been at this for days now. This is rather hard to understand I'll read it some more to fully grasp the idea. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

First, I would reformat the array

```
[100, 200, 500, 600, 150, 250]
```

into something more explicit, such as

```
[ {'start':100, 'end':200}, {'start':500, 'end':600}, {'start':150, 'end':250} ]
```

which is clearly an array of intervals.  Now, here is a solution which is easy to code, but not efficient:

For each pair of intervals in the array, check to see if they overlap (that is, if the 'start' of one interval is between the 'start' and 'end' of the other, or the 'end' of one interval is between the 'start' and 'end' of the other).  If they overlap, delete both intervals from the array and replace it with the new COMBINED interval (new interval will have 'start' equal to the minimum of the starts of the two intervals, and 'end' equal to the maximum of the ends of the two intervals).

Repeat this process until you iterate once through all the pairs of the array without the array getting shorter.  You are done.